# How can I accomplish this in Objective-C? Developing an app for a web-app with no API, how can I log users in?

Tags: objective-c, c, screen-scraping

I want to develop an iOS app for a website which has no API. Users can login to this website and view information, and download files. My app will be simply a native mobile interface for this website, downloading the data from the website and displaying it nicely in the app, natively.

Therefore the app must meet the following criteria:

1. Be able to download webpage data
2. Be able to analyse the webpage data and pull relevant information
   from the source code
3. Be able to log users in to the website and store their session data
   in the app

Does anybody know how I can accomplish this, particularly #3? Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm planning on using a NSURLConnection to download the data but I'm afraid to say I'm completely stuck as to #3. I'm really hoping to get some advice on that particular point because I'm clueless! Any links or theory would be much appreciated

Comment: By the way, site "scraping" hasn't been conclusively shown to be legal (and in some cases, terms of service state that you cannot, however the legality of that is also unclear). You may wish to seek permission from the owner of the website.

Comment: Hey Jack, that's definitely an issue I'll consider - thanks very much. I know the developers personally but I will approach them first as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server code you should write an API to allow your app to access what it needs. If you do not, it seems a bit shady managing user info to a site you have no access to.